# How to configure logwatch to monitor a custom log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, logwatch

Ubuntu Server 9.10

Hi Guys,

Could someone point me to some instructions for how to get logwatch to monitor a custom log file?  I have a dropbox solution that documents uploads/downloads to a log file and would like to include it in the updates from logwatch.

I tried creating a custom conf file in /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/ but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Could you add the config you tried, and any log output that seems relevant? Eg, anything mentioning that the file couldn't be read, or had a syntax error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A starter point is the LogWatch Documentation page for [HOWTO Customize LogWatch](http://web.archive.org/web/20080822051428/http://www.logwatch.org/tabs/docs/HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch.html).
Read through points 4, 5 and 6.

Another brief description of the LogWatch files -- [Managing your log files](http://tuxradar.com/content/managing-your-log-files).
And, a Metalog wiki reference on [how to setup logwatch to read metalog generated log files](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Logwatch_with_Metalog).